# How to overcome pop up shile replaying recorded Selenium IDE

Tags: html

I recorded application in selenium IDE HTML format after replaying this is the error that is displaying "Firefox prevented this site from opening pop up window"

```
 In selenium IDE in log we got error like this "[warn] Opening window '_blank', which is not a real window name. Randomizing target to be: selenium_blank54652" 

  how do i solve this problem?
```

Answer (score 0):

Give that window a `name`, example:

```
window.open('url', 'name_here', 'more_options');
```